# Javascript code for Category

Tags: categories, javascript

can I check if scripting can be encrypted for specific categories? For example, I would like to encrypt  only for http://www.example.com/category/news/education,  for http://www.example.com/category/news/dogs, so on and so forth.

Thanks!

Regards,
Jeremy

Comment: Encrypt what? What are you trying to do exactly? Enqueue a script on a category? ...or?

Answer (score -2):

Write this in your theme's functions.php file

```
function category_enqueue_script() {
    $cat_education_id = 'xx'; // category id for "education"
    $cat_dog_id = 'yy'; // category id for "dog"
    if ( is_category() && ( is_category( $cat_education_id ) || is_category( $cat_dog_id ) ) ) {
         wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', 'filename.js', false );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'category_enqueue_script' );
```

Comment: This answer is totally off-topic. Your code shows how to enqueue a script, but that´s probably not what the poster wanted to ask for. Besides that your code is not very good, do you want to make 20 `&&` operators, if you have 20 categories/posts/whatevers?

Comment: If your answer answeres the question, there are much better ways to achieve that. As @flomei stated, if you have 20 categories under news, will you run twenty conditional checks